# How do I stream a chunked file using Node.js Readable?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, stream, streaming, fs

I have a 400Mb file split into chunks that are ~1Mb each.

Each chunk is a MongoDB document:

```
{
  name: 'stuff.zip',
  index: 15,
  buffer: Binary('......'),
  totalChunks: 400
}
```

I am fetching each chunk from my database and then streaming it to the client.

Every time I get chunk from the DB I push it to the readableStream which is being piped to the client.

Here is the code:

```
import { Readable } from 'stream'

const name = 'stuff.zip'
const contentType = 'application/zip'

app.get('/api/download-stuff', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', contentType)
  res.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${name}`)
  res.attachment(name)

  // get `totalChunks` from random chunk
  let { totalChunks } = await ChunkModel.findOne({ name }).select('totalChunks')

  let index = 0

  const readableStream = new Readable({
    async read() {
      if (index < totalChunks) {

        let { buffer } = await ChunkModel.findOne({ name, index }).select('buffer')
        let canContinue = readableStream.push(buffer)
        console.log(`pushed chunk ${index}/${totalChunks}`)
        index++

        // sometimes it logs false
        // which means I should be waiting before pushing more
        // but I don't know how
        console.log('canContinue = ', canContinue)

      } else {

        readableStream.push(null)
        readableStream.destroy()
        console.log(`all ${totalChunks} chunks streamed to the client`)

      }
    }
  })

  readableStream.pipe(res)
})
```

The code works.

But I'm wondering whether I risk having memory overflows on my local server memory, especially when the requests for the same file are too many or the chunks are too many.

**Question:** My code is not waiting for `readableStream` to finish reading the chunk that was just pushed to it, before pushing the next one. I thought it was, and that is why I'm using `read(){..}` in this probably wrong way. So **how should I wait for each chunk to be pushed, read, streamed to the client and cleared from my server's local memory, before I push the next one in ?**

*I have created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-silence-ds16pr?file=/chunk.js) in case it helps anyone*

Comment: Note that this implementation reads one document at a time and waits for the data to be transferred to the client before reading the next chunk from DB. Instead, it could be improved performance-wise by filling up the read buffer to `highWatermark`.

Answer (score 0):

**In general**, when the readable interface is implemented correctly (i.e., the backpressure signal is respected), the readable interface will prevent the code from overflowing the memory regardless of source size.

When implemented according to the API spec, the readable itself does not keep references for data that has finished passing through the stream. The memory requirement of a readable buffer is adjusted by specifying a `highWatermark`.

**In this case**, the snippet does not conform to the readable interface. It violates the following two concepts:

1. No data shall be pushed to the readable's buffer unless read() has been called. Currently, this implementation proceeds to push data from DB immediately. Consequently, the readable buffer will start to fill before the sink has begun to consume data.
2. The readable's `push()` method returns a boolean flag. When the flag is `false`, the implementation *must* wait for `.read()` to be called before pushing additional data. If the flag is ignored, the buffer will overflow wrt. the `highWatermark`.

Note that ignoring these core criteria of Readables circumvents the backpressure logic.

**An alternative** implementation, if this is a Mongoose query:

```js
app.get('/api/download-stuff', async (req, res) => {
  // ... truncated handler  
  
  // A helper variable to relay data from the stream to the response body
  const passThrough = new stream.PassThrough({objectMode: false});

  // Pipe data using pipeline() to simplify handling stream errors
  stream.pipeline(
    // Create a cursor that fetch all relevant documents using a single query
    ChunkModel.find().limit(chunksLength).select("buffer").sort({index: 1}).lean().cursor(),
    // Cherry pick the `buffer` property
    new stream.Transform({
      objectMode: true,
      transform: ({ buffer }, encoding, next) => {
        next(null, buffer);
      }
    }),
    // Write the retrieved documents to the helper variable
    passThrough,
    error => {
      if(error){
        // Log and handle error. At this point the HTTP headers are probably already sent,
        // and it is therefore too late to return HTTP500
      }
    }
  );

  res.body = passThrough;
});
```

Comment: As you see in my OP, I do not wish to send an object to the client. I only want to send the value of `buffer` prop. Also, you said that your code is fetching *all* documents but won't this cause problems with the local server memory ? That's why I was "trying" to fetch them one-by-one instead. Unless I'm not reading your code correctly and you're not "literally" fetching *all* documents into the server's local memory.

Comment: Sorry i'm not very experienced with DBs and servers and which memory is used when. Ideally data should be sent directly from the DB to the client with nothing saved on the server even temporarily no? Server should only confirm that it's ok for the DB to send that piece of data to the client directly.. But again, I'm not experienced in this..

Comment: (1) I've updated the example snippet to deconstruct a `buffer` property. (2) This fetches documents with as high throughput as sustainable wrt. the `highWatermark`. I.e., it won't overflow. (3) The data *must* be in the server's memory momentarily to be moved across the read/write buffers. (4) Yes, the final remark you made tends to be how API access control are structured

Comment: I tried your solution and I get a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: stream.on is not a function` from `/streams/pipeline.js`

Comment: What version of node and mongoose are you running?

Comment: I'm on Node 12.22 and Mongoose 6.1. - I have update the OP with what I think is a better implementation that eliminates the risk of memory overflow (?) Could be totally wrong though :)

Comment: Async generators are supported from v13. I've updated the snippet to be compatible with node v12

Comment: Thank you for the update. I will try later today and let you know (!)

Comment: I tried it. No error is thrown anymore but nothing is sent to the client either. The transform callback is called `{chunksLength}` times as expected though. I need to clarify that the `get('...')` handler is called when the user clicks on a `<a>` to get the file as an attachment. That is why I'm also defining the headers shown on the OP.

Comment: Maybe `res.body = passThrough` is not the correct approach ? Also note that I had to do `next(null, Buffer.from(buffer))` instead, otherwise I was getting an error..